# Use encrypted database in react-native

Tags: react-native, encryption, sqlcipher

I need to create an encrypted database using SQL-cipher in react-native. To do that I found a react-native-sqlite-storage [fork](https://github.com/dryganets/react-native-sqlite-storage/tree/sergeyd/sqlite-cipher) modified by Dryganet but there is no documentation to use it.

I've just started to look into react-native so any lead would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I looked into it and the syntax for the fork is this:

```
errorCB(err) {
  console.log("SQL Error: " + err);
},

openCB() {
  console.log("Database OPENED");
},

var database = await SQLite.openDatabase({"name": "test.db", "key": "password"}, openCB, errorCB);
```

And the funny thing is it was right in front me XD.

One can also use [Realm database](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest). It's easy to use and well documented and it supports react-native.